# Not sure which class I should put my method in

Tags: java, architecture

I'm currently working on a simple 2D grid game. The grid of the game is composed of cells. A cell can contain (among other things) a landmine or a bomb.
The classes that relate to my problem are: *Player* ; *Board* and *Game*

This is how my classes are used within each other:

The class *Game* represents a game in all its details:

```
public class Game
{
    private Board board;

    private Player player;

    //Currently using
    public void placeMine(Player owner, int x, int y);
}
```

The *Board* class is mainly a 2D array of *Cell*

```
public class Board
{
    private Cell[][] board;
}
```

The *Cell* class can contain a mine

```
public class Cell
{
    private boolean containsMine;
}
```

The *Player* class represents a player. A player should be capable of placing a landmine or a bomb on the board.

```
public class Player
{
    //placeMine() here ?
    public void placeMine(int x, int y);
}
```

Now the question is : Where should I put my `placeMine()` method?

My "real life logic" makes me want to put `placeMine()` in *Player* as it is logically a Player who places a mine on the ground. However, doing that means that the *Player* class has to have access to the instance of Board (as the mine is going to be placed on the board. On a cell of the board more precisely).

Giving the *Player* class an instance of *Board* sounds very bad as a Player doesn't "possess" a *Board*. The instance of Board could be given to the `placeMine()` method as an argument but I'm not too sure how I feel about doing this.

The other alternative, which I'm currently using, is having `placeMine()` in *Game*. It is much easier to make it work this way and simpler to comprehend I believe. It feels less of an instance passing festival than if I had to pass an entire Board each time.
But it doesn't really suit the intuition I have about the whole thing (which is that a *Player* places a mine, not that a *Game* place a mine).

What would be the best way of doing this if the whole point is to have a clear, understandable, scalable architecture?

Comment: `placeMine` modifies data of the `Board`, right? So it should be primarily there. However there's nothing stopping you from placing it in the `Player` class, where it could simply delegate to the method in `Board`.

Comment: you can also have one placeMine method that calls another placeMine method.

Comment: Hi, good explained question. I don't think you are right that only a Player can place a mine. What if you play against a Computer? I agree with @f1sh answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `placeMine()` method belongs in the `Game` class.

The architecture of your game is logically divided into (Model-View-Controller):

- Model:  Board / Cell
- Controller:  Game
- Helper classes:  Player (and Mine could be another if it had other properties)

The model contains the game's state.  The controller is responsible for managing each turn of the game, and updating the state accordingly.  The game's actions are dealt with by the controller.  While a Player is the 'owner' of a turn, and perhaps the owner of a cell, etc, it is the Game which is placing a mine on any given turn on behalf of the player, and updating the state accordingly.